# How to select these elements with Xpath?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have a document, something like this:

```
<root>
   <A node="1"/>
   <B node="2"/>
   <A node="3"/>
   <A node="4"/>
   <B node="5"/>
   <B node="6"/>
   <A node="7"/>
   <A node="8"/>
   <B node="9"/>
</root>
```

Using xpath, How can I select all B elements that consecutively follow a given A element?

It's something like following-silbing::B, except I want them to be only the *immediately following* elements.

If I am on A (node==1), then I want to select node 2.
If I am on A (node==3), then I want to select nothing. 
If I am on A (node==4), then I want to select 5 and 6.

Can I do this in xpath? *EDIT*: It is within an XSL stylesheet select statement.

---

*EDIT2*: I don't want to use the node attribute on the various elements as a unique identifier.  I included the node attribute only for purposes of illustrating my point. In the actual XML doc, I don't have an attribute that I use as a unique identifer. The xpath         "following-sibling::UL[preceding-sibling::LI[1]/@node = current()/@node]"
keys on the node attribute, and that's not what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer (assuming current() is ok, since this is tagged xslt):

```
following-sibling::B[preceding-sibling::A[1]/@node = current()/@node]
```

Example stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/A"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="A">
        <div>A: <xsl:value-of select="@node"/></div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::B[preceding-sibling::A[1]/@node = current()/@node]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="B">
        <div>B: <xsl:value-of select="@node"/></div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Good luck!

Comment: So helpful to remind me that `current()` can help position statements for relative logic.

Answer (score 3):

While @Chris Nielsen's answer is the right approach, it leaves an uncertainty in cases where the compared attribute is not unique. The more correct way of solving this is:

```
following-sibling::B[
  generate-id(preceding-sibling::A[1]) = generate-id(current())
]
```

This makes sure that the `preceding-sibling::A` is *identical* to the current `A`, instead of just comparing some attribute values. Unless you have attributes that are guaranteed to be unique, this is the only safe way.

Comment: +1;  I was going to say following-sibling::B[count(preceding-sibling::A[1] | current()) = 1], but your way seems more understandable.

Comment: IMHO, the `count(...)` method to determine node identity is semantically inferior to the `generate-id()` method, but occasionally I use it as well. Depends a bit on the context, but in general I prefer `generate-id()` for being more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

A solution might be to first gather up all the following nodes using `following-sibling::*`, grab the first of these and require it to be a 'B' node.

```
following-sibling::*[position()=1][name()='B']
```